# Print only clicked radio button value(React)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects, radio-group

Print selected radio button value in console.
If all radiogroup is answered then print in console only the selected= true radioValue. for example: if NO radiobutton= true its value is 2. It should print value 2. Like that all true radiovalue should print in console.
Thanks

```js
//array of cards coming from the backend
const data = [
  {
    cardName: 'Do you want  sugar in your coffee',
    options: [
    { radioName: 'Yes',radioValue: '1', selected: false },
    { radioName: 'No',radioValue: '2', selected: false }]
  },
  {
    cardName: 'Do you want  milk in your coffee', 
    options: [
    { radioName: 'Yes',radioValue: '1', selected: false },
    { radioName: 'No',radioValue: '2', selected: false }]
  },
  {
    cardName: 'Do you want  low-fat-milk in your coffee', 
    options: [
    { radioName: 'Yes',radioValue: '1', selected: false },
    { radioName: 'No',radioValue: '2', selected: false }]
  }
];


class CardsList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
cards: [],

    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // mimic an async server call
      this.setState({ cards: data });
    }, 1000);
  }

  onInputChange = ({ target }) => {
    const { cards } = this.state;
    const nexState = cards.map(card => {
      if (card.cardName !== target.name) return card;
      return {
        ...card,
        options: card.options.map(opt => {
          const checked = opt.radioName === target.value;
          return {
            ...opt,
            selected: checked
          }
        })
      }
    });
    this.setState({ cards: nexState })
  }

  onSubmit = () => { 
 console.log(this.state.cards.map(({ cardName, options }) => {
  const option = options.filter(({ selected }) => selected)[0]
  return ` ${option.radioValue}`
}))
  };

 onReset = () => {
        this.setState({cards:[]});
      }
  render() {
    const { cards } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {
          cards.length < 1 ? "Loading..." :
            <div>
              {cards.map((card, idx) => (
                <ul>
                  {card.cardName}
                  {card.options.radioName}

                  {
                    card.options.map((lo, idx) => {
                      return <input
                        key={idx}
                        type="radio"
                        name={card.cardName}
                        value={lo.radioName}
                        checked={!!lo.selected}
                        onChange={this.onInputChange}
                      />

                    })
                  }
                </ul>
              ))
              }
              < button onClick={this.onSubmit}>Submit</button>
               < button onClick={this.onReset}>Clear</button>
            </div>
        }

      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<CardsList />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your log in `onSubmit` to this

```
console.log(this.state.cards.map(({ cardName, options }) => {
  const option = options.filter(({ selected }) => selected)[0]
  return `${cardName}: ${option.radioName}`
}))
```

This way you filter the options to the one, where `selected` is truthy, and take the first one.

To address your first question, just map over your `this.state.cards` array before doing the log and check, if there is exactly 1 `option`, where `selected` is true. If this is not the case, tell the user in whatever way you want.

Also you can remove your constructor and change it to that:

```
state = {
    cards: [],
}
```

Because you do not access your props in your constructor

Answer (score 1):

You can go with the answer of @george,

for you to check if either of the radio buttons is clicked for each card, you can run a validation check

```
let unselectedCards = this.state.cards.filter((card) => {
   return !card.options[0].selected && !card.options[1].selected
});
```

use the unselectedCards variable to highlight the cards.

you can use map options again inside the cards map if you would be having more options.